# lua coroutine as iterator: cannot resume dead coroutine

Tags: lua, iterator, coroutine

there,

I modified the "perm" example from Lua 5.0 online document: http://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html. What I did is to repoint the __call() metamethod to the perm() function. But it only works once, and reported "cannot resume dead coroutine". Any idea why it didn't work?

```
function permgen (a, n)
  if n == 0 then
 coroutine.yield(a)
  else
    for i=1,n do

      -- put i-th element as the last one
      a[n], a[i] = a[i], a[n]

      -- generate all permutations of the other elements
      permgen(a, n - 1)

      -- restore i-th element
      a[n], a[i] = a[i], a[n]

    end
  end
end

function perm (a)
  local n = table.getn(a)
  return coroutine.wrap(function () permgen(a, n) end)
end

K = {"a","b","c"}


for p in perm(K)  do
   print(p[1],p[2],p[3])
end


for p in perm(K)  do
   print(p[1],p[2],p[3])
end

-- everything above is copied from the Lua online document,
-- my modification is the following
setmetatable(K,{__call=perm(K)})
for p in K  do
   print(p[1],p[2],p[3])
end

-- cannot repeat!
-- perm.lua:44: cannot resume dead coroutine
for p in K  do
   print(p[1],p[2],p[3])
end
```

`

Comment: You set `__call` to the *result* of calling `perm(K)`. Did you mean to make `__call` actually *call* the `perm` function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you call `perm(K)` once and assign the result to the `__call` metamethod. You then *use* it once (by doing `in K`) and that completes the execution of the coroutine returned by the `perm` call. When you try to do it the second time, the coroutine is already "dead", which triggers the error.

What you need to do is to detect if the coroutine is already dead and re-create it. Since you can't do this with `coroutine.wrap`, you need to use a slightly modified version of the solution using `coroutine.create`. Something like this may work:

```
function perm (a)
  local n = table.getn(a)
  local co = coroutine.create(function () permgen(a, n) end)
  return function ()   -- iterator
    if coroutine.status(co) == 'dead' then co = coroutine.create(function () permgen(a, n) end) end
    local code, res = coroutine.resume(co)
    if not code then return nil end
    return res
  end
end
```

It checks the status of the coroutine before resuming and if it's already `dead`, then it recreates it from scratch using the same parameters.